# sed - how to delete more that one space in a row?

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file with :

```
STRING.STRING2.STRING3            = VALUE1 bla bla text bla bla
```

And i want to obtain something like this:

```
<string name="STRING.STRING2.STRING3">VALUE1 bla bla text bla bla</string>
```

using only shell commands like *grep* or *sed* and others

until now i reached to that:

```
TEMP=`cat $file |
        sed '/^\#/d' $file       
        sed 's@=@">@'                
        sed 's@\.@_@g'               
        sed 's:(\\s){3}::g'`                

echo "$TEMP " | sed 's@^@<string name="@'  |
        sed 's@$@</string>@'
```

(also the 5th doesnt work too well...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use bash, can be done completely in the shell:

```
str="STRING.STRING2.STRING3            = VALUE1 bla bla text bla bla"
shopt -s extglob
IFS="+( )=+( )"
read v1 v2 <<< "$str"
printf '<string name="%s">%s</string>\n' "$v1" "$v2"
```

produces

```
<string name="STRING.STRING2.STRING3">VALUE1 bla bla text bla bla</string>
```

Edit: to process a file

```
shopt -s extglob
while IFS="+( )=+( )" read v1 v2; do 
  printf '<string name="%s">%s</string>\n' "$v1" "$v2"
done < filename
```

Comment: super !! but how i can modify this to do that for each line form a given filename ?

Comment: wow !  strange thing: same annoying problem while first version of answer produces the good output, the edited answer (the second) includes all the spaces before "=".. Whi is happening that ?

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
awk -F= '{gsub(/[[:space:]]*/,"",$1); gsub(/^[[:space:]]*/,"",$2); print "<string name=\""$1"\">"$2"</string>"}' test.txt
```

where text.txt is your file

Comment: wow!!! almoust perfect!!! but it still give me alot of spaces:
<string name="KEY                    ">has been tampered with.</string>
can you extract that spaces after KEY ?

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -r 's/^([^ ]+) *= *(.+)$/<string name="\1">\2<\/string>/' < file
```

Comment: I would not be too strict about spaces, so I would use `'s/^([^ ]+) *= *(.+)$/<string name="\1">\2<\/string>/' as pattern.

Comment: @arnep Agreed, but it's however depends on the data

Comment: incredible perfect !! and fast too!!  from here I think I can manage.. tank you !